# unable to run mysql v8.0.31 on tomcat 9.0.74

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, java-8, tomcat9

Getting the below error log while running the tomcat:-

```
May 12, 2023 9:45:04 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@34c45dca;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: Image-Text
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@34c45dca

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:227)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:768)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:696)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:495)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:560)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:244)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:332)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:864)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:850)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:986)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4852)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1184)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1932)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1094)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:476)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@34c45dca;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: Image-Text
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@34c45dca

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:56)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:304)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38)
    ... 60 more

May 12, 2023 9:45:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: [javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception resolving reference [Root exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@34c45dca;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: Image-Text
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@34c45dca
]]
May 12, 2023 9:45:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [Faces Servlet] as unavailable
May 12, 2023 9:45:04 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Faces Servlet] in web application [/Image-Text] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1020)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:960)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
```

mysql dependency used :-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.31</version>
        </dependency>
```

i'm using tomcat 9.0.74 and mysql 8.0.31 and jdk8, i'm currentely upgrading my project from jdk7 to 8 and tomcat 7 to 9 and mysql 5 to 8. there's been many issue and most of them resolved by changing the dependency versions but this i'm not able to resolve.
i tried changing the mysql versions but didn't work

Adding some more error logs these logs are the starting logs they were missing because of some eclipse settings: -

```
May 12, 2023 10:34:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class [org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4946)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:689)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1888)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:582)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)

May 12, 2023 10:34:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
May 12, 2023 10:34:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
May 12, 2023 10:34:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
May 12, 2023 10:34:44 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
May 12, 2023 10:34:44 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:144)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:91)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
May 12, 2023 10:34:44 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
May 12, 2023 10:34:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of deployment descriptor [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.74\apache-tomcat-9.0.74\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml] has finished in [13,985] ms
May 12, 2023 10:34:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive [D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.74\apache-tomcat-9.0.74\webapps\abc.war]
May 12, 2023 10:34:46 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1432)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1057)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkThreadContextClassLoader(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:123)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:90)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Adding context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application --><Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources. If one of these changes, the    -->
    <!-- web application will be reloaded.                                   -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <!--<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>-->

    
 <Resource auth="Container" defaultAutoCommit="false" 
defaultTransactionIsolation="2" driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" 
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" maxIdle="30" 
name="jdbc/myDS" password="1234" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3307/latest?characterEncoding=UTF-8" 
username="root" validationQuery="SELECT 1 from dual"/>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->
</Context>
```

Comment: The classname (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver) is incorrect for that version of the Connector-J driver.

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-driver-name.html

Comment: getting this error now "Unable to load class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@34c45dca;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
"

Comment: Is the JAR for the driver in your WAR file?   Check.

Comment: "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkStateForResourceLoading
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
"at the endoferrorlog

Comment: by this "Is the JAR for the driver in your WAR file" do you mean in my repository default one that starts with .m2/....

Comment: No.  I mean the WAR file that Maven is building and that you are deploying to your Tomcat.

Comment: yes in my abc/web-inf/lib folder "mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar" is present

Comment: You need to show the `Context.xml` in which this resource is defined to Tomcat, but your question is really off topic here.

Comment: I suspect you may need to copy that JAR to the tomcat shared library folder.  I'm not sure whether the Tomcat DataSource config is going to search your webapp's classpath.

Comment: added the context.xml file

Comment: @StephenC is correct. If that is the Tomcat Context.xml rather than the application's, and it appears to be, the driver JAR file needs to be in the Tomcat lib directory. However, contrary to another comment, both `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` and `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` are present in the JAR, and I think they have gone back to preferring the former.

Comment: Ah.  OK.  So we suspect that >neither< version of the driver JAR was in the shared lib folder.